# JS push operation does something funny to repeated array arguments

Tags: push

I don't understand js's push. It does this funny thing

```
var x = []
var y = [1]
x.push(y)   // x is [[1]]
x.push(y)   // x is [[1],[]]   Why?
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code I get:
x is [[1],[1]]
as the output - run fiddle at bottom...

I have no idea how you could be getting a different output?

```js
var x = [];
var y = [1];
x.push(y)   // x is [[1]]
x.push(y)   // x is [[1],[]]

var divOut = document.getElementById('divOut');
divOut.innerText = 'x is ' + JSON.stringify(x);
```

```html
<div id="divOut"></div>
```